# set up Concurrent ML in smlnj

Tags: sml, smlnj, concurrent-programming

I am trying to get Concurret ML run in SMLNJ. I saw a post about using CM.make to do this but I could not find CM.make file on my system. Please tell how to resolve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I can load the library directly. For instance, in my case I could do

```
sml /opt/smlnj/cml/src/cml.cm
```

Knowing where the library is located, you could use CM.make. For instance, in my REPL if I do

```
CM.make "/opt/smlnj/cml/src/cml.cm";
```

It loads the CML library. With either approach if I do:

```
val r = CML.version
```

I get:

```
val r = {date="September 15, 1997",system="Concurrent ML",version_id=[1,0,10]}
  : {date:string, system:string, version_id:int list}
```

The CM library should already be available in your current installation of SML. I did not have to do anything special to load it.

See the [SML/NJ FAQ](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/FAQ/usage.html#loadLib) in the section about loading libraries.

Comment: Do I need to do anything extra to do CML programming in a file through text editor